# add list to previous list in same line

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I have two lists:

```
 "list1": [
            "xxxx"
            "yyyyy",
            "yyyyy",
            "yyyyy",
        ]
```

```
 "list2": [
            "xxxx"
            "yyyyy",
            "yyyyy",
            "yyyyy",
        ]
```

I do a loop on list2 to add it to list1, it works but adds it in new line like this:

```
        "xxxx",
        "yyyyy",
        "yyyyy",
        "yyyyy,
        "xxxx",
        "yyyyy",
        "yyyyy",
        "yyyyy",
```

the loop I used

```
    set_fact:
      list1: "{{ list1 |default([]) + list2 }}"
    loop: "{{ list2 }}"
```

meanwhile expected result:

```
            "xxxxxxxx",
            "yyyyyyyyyy",
            "yyyyyyyyyy",
            "yyyyyyyyyy,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) data

```yaml
  l1: [a, b, c]
  l2: [d, e, f]
```

Join the items on the lists. The expected result is

```yaml
  l3: [ad, be, cf]
```

---

A: *zip* the lists and *join* the items. The expression below gives the expected result

```yaml
  l3: "{{ l1|zip(l2)|map('join')|list }}"
```

---

Example of a complete playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    l1: [a, b, c]
    l2: [d, e, f]
    l3: "{{ l1|zip(l2)|map('join')|list }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: l3
```

Comment: This is a really simple and easy to understand minimal example for [Combining items from multiple lists: `zip`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-items-from-multiple-lists-zip-and-zip-longest) together [Data manipultaion - List comprehensions with `map('join')`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/complex_data_manipulation.html#loops-and-list-comprehensions).